# CakePHP 1.3: Integrating Google Analytics PHP Interface (GAPI) with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, google-analytics

I am attempting to use the following GAPI class to access my Google Analytics for information regarding pageviews, etc.

http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/

However, I have not been able to set it up successfully as the integrations that cake with this class is not as detailed as I would like to see it.

Can anyone help me out setting this up?

Comment: You'll have to define what it is exactly that you want to achieve. 'Not as detailed as I would like to see it' doesn't tell us what you _do_ want to see...

Comment: Basically, I wanted to see some instructions on how to set it up so it works on my site, the basics. And then if possible some examples I can improve on... thanks